# print a square with stars and remove it's diagonal

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am trying to print a square and remove it's diagonal from the right 
like

```
********** 
********* *
******** **
******* ***
****** ****
***** *****
**** ******
*** *******
** ********
* *********
 **********
```

i was able to remove the diameter from the left using the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int h,v,num;
    cout<<"Give a value for length ";
    cin>>v;
    cout<<"Give a value for width ";
    cin>>h;
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
    {
        for(int r=0;r<h;r++)
        {
        if (i==r)
            cout<<" ";
        else
            cout<<"*";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: I don't get it.  Squares do not have a diameter.

Comment: probably `diameter => diagonal`

Comment: `if (i==r)` you just change that condition like `if (w-i==r)`

Comment: yes sorry for my bad english i mean diagonal not diameter

Comment: thanks  πάντα ῥεῖ 
  if (h-i==r) is worked

Comment: @AshrafEldawody Sorry. Your variable naming is extremely confusing and meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int v;
    cout<<"Give a value for length ";
    cin>>v;
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
    {
        for(int r=0;r<v;r++)
        {
        if ((i + r) == (v - 1))
            cout<<" ";
        else
            cout<<"*";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

[Try it here!](http://ideone.com/7yYM7y)

Don't let the user insert width and length, because you want to print a square anyway. If someone enters two different variables you have a problem.

The calculation `(i + r)` will always be `(v - 1)` on the diagonal from right top to bottom left. If you want it the other direction you can use the `i == r` like you already have.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int height,width,d;
    cout<<"Give a value for height : ";
    cin>>height;
    cout<<"Give a value for width : ";
    cin>>width;
    d=width-1;
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
        {
            if (j==d)
            {
                cout<<" ";
                d--;
            }

            else
                cout<<"*";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```